# Importing Sylpheed accounts to new computer

Tags: email, accounts, sylpheed

I was using Sylpheed on my old computer with Kubuntu 12.04 LTS

I have just installed Sylpheed on my new computer with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Is there a way of transferring / importing my email account settings without having to configure them all manually?

Comment: please refer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515880),....(but i'm not sure)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.The issue is not how to import the mail folders, but that I have 15 email addresses set up on Sylpheed. I am trying to find a way to import the settings for those to my new installation, so I won't have to configure each one of them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Sylpheed is everything easy.

Copy `.sylpheed` folder and all inbox folder of mail accounts from your `/home/username` to new pc and this is it.

Start Sylpheed and all aka accounts, structure and setting will be there.

Comment: Thanks, that saved a lot of time. It looks like it worked fine, even though the new computer has a newer version of Sylpheed installed and is using a different version of Ubuntu.